# How to rewriting the URL using .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How to rewrite a URL from `localhost/folder/abc.php?p_id=1` to `localhost/folder/xyx/1`.

I tried lots of methods but still couldn't rewrite the URL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^xyx/(.+)$   folder/abc.php?p_id=$1   [L]
```

Comment: "rewrite a URL from `localhost/folder/abc.php?p_id=1` to `localhost/folder/xyx/1`" - it would seem to be the other way round... _from_ `/folder/xyx/1` _to_ `/folder/abc.php?p_id=1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule inside `folder/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^xyz/(.+\.(?:css|js))$ /folder/$1 [L,R=301,NE,NC]

RewriteRule ^xyz/(.+) abc.php?p_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Still not working and the CSS link look like localhost/folder/xyz/assets/css/style.css

Comment: Yes, inside the folder I put the .htaccess file. Not getting the 404 error but the CSS and JS file links look like localhost/folder/xyz/assets/css/style.css

Comment: Where is your css file located?

Comment: folder/assets/css/style

Comment: ok css/js issue is due to use of relative path. add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/folder/" />`

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are 404 URLs you get.

Comment: Also try my updated answer for fixing css/js paths.